# Always run one instance of Kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

How to configure Kubernetes deployment to run only one replica of pod always ? We can configure replicas as 1 in the deployment file but this will not prevent someone from scaling up pods using kubectl.

Comment: Any luck implementing this? We are on a managed cluster and not able to create mutating webhooks

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly restrict a Deployment resource to not allow more than one replica.

But you could create a custom [ValidatingAdmissionWebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#validatingadmissionwebhook) admission controller that rejects requests that try to modify the `replicas` field of this Deployment.

Or you could create a Custom Resource Definition (CRD) that has a similar behaviour as a Deployment, but has the number of replicas fixed to 1.

In general, if you just want to prevent certain users from scaling a replica, you could restrict the RBAC permissions for these users to prevent them from updating Deployment objects.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [mutating webhook controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/).

*Any* pod could be limited to a specific number of replicas this way.

Probably overkill for what you are trying to achieve, but it would work.

Comment: Probably better to use a validation hook and reject changes that don't match, Open Policy Agent is an easy way to do this. Well, easy-ish.